# url handling with web.py and extjs

Tags: apache, url, extjs, mod-wsgi, web.py

I'm porting a program from turbogears to web.py/mod_wsgi with pretty good success.  I've setup the URL handling similar to turbogears, but I'm running into a minor annoyance in how extjs 2.0 handles URLs.

Say my app is named "ack", I can test it by going to either http://localhost/ack or http://localhost/ack/ (note the trailing slash as the only difference).  From a web.py point of view, this doesn't matter.  However, in the template I'm using that was written in extjs, I designate urls to query information from the app using JSON (example below).

```
var nameListStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
url: 'nameList',
root: 'nameList',
autoLoad: true,
fields: ['name'],
});
```

Here's the trouble.  If I access my app using the trailing slash, than extjs forms the a url query like http://localhost/ack/nameList, which calls my app's function and gets the correct data back.  If I don't have the trailing slash in the address bar, extjs builds the url as http://localhost/nameList, which never makes it to my application and literally every JSON query fails (as shown in my firebug console).

I assume extjs is just ripping off anything trailing the last slash to build the url, but I'd like to fix that.  Right now I'm just telling my users to make sure they run the app with the trailing slash, but this seems like a simple thing to handle.  I just don't know how in extjs.